# Can the bug with class 10 SDHC cards be fixed in firmware?

Tags: sd-card, bugs

It seems relatively well known now that there's a lot of problems with class 10 SDHC cards:

> There are issues with most Class 10 SDHC cards, apparently due to a bug in the Broadcom bootloader.[(link)](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#SD_cards)

Is this a problem that can be fixed with a later firmware update, or will it likely require the purchase of a new device?

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question is being closed? It seems to me it should be answerable at some point.

Comment: @Jivings I was about to post the same thing - in honesty, I think it's a wider problem: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/134/are-close-votes-being-used-without-enough-thought

Comment: From chat by @dunsmoreb "The question deals with Broadcom, not RPi."

Comment: Personally, I disagree. This question is quite clearly related to RPi hardware.

Comment: [Question asks to predict the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20668/188212). VTC.

Comment: @finnw I disagree it's a prediction, see my comment here: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/134